# Computing the sum of an infinite series involving factorial terms

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Compute the sum of the infinite series

$$\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{n^{2}+3n+1}{n!}
$$

My intuition suggests that this converges to some multiple of $e$. But I don´t know what trick I have to use to find the sum. Should I change the summation index for instance?

Comment: Use the identity $n^2+3n+1=n(n-1)+4n+1$ and split the series into three parts.

Answer (score 2):

intuitively we have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{n^2 + 3n + 1}{n!} & = \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{n^2}{n!} + \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{3n}{n!} +\sum_{n \geq 0}  \frac{1}{n!} \\
& = \sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{n^2}{n!} + 3 \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{1}{(n-1)!} + e \\
& =  \sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{n}{(n-1)!} + 3 \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{(n-1)!} + e \\
& =  \sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{n}{(n-1)!} + 3 \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{1}{n!} + e \\
& =  \sum_{n \geq 0}\frac{n+1}{n!} + 3 \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{1}{n!} + e 
\end{align*}
and remember
$$
xe^x = \sum_{n =0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{n!},\quad e^x + xe^x = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1)x^n}{n!} 
$$

Comment: Why did you change the index in the first summand of the second equality?

Comment: $\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{n^2}{n!} = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{n^2}{n!}$ because the first one term evaluated at $0$, is $0$, so it doesn't contribute anything, and in $\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{1}{(n-1)!} = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{(n-1)!}$ It is because it is not defined (-1)!

Comment: Yes I had understood from the third equality, it was just in the second equality because you didn’t change anything in the argument of the sum.